# How would I test a bunch of Audio CDs?

Tags: windows, linux, audio-cd

I have fifteen Audio CDs - an Audiobook - that I haven't used in ages.

I would like to pass them on, but before doing that, I want to check whether they still work flawlessly.

Is there a Windows or Linux program that I can use to quality test a CD? Is possible, with a detailed explanation of any errors it may find, and whether they will cause problems listening to the CD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing `-Z` to `cdparanoia` will disable all error checking and correcting. `-X` will cause it to exit on the slightest error. Both together will check if the disc is pristine. Less-than-perfect discs can be played in a player, so you may want to try `-Y` instead of `-Z` as well if it fails.